# How can I get out of social situations with my boss

Tags: job-security

I started working at a thrift store and my first week the owner of the store asked me out. everyone seemed to hang out there so I said it would be okay if he met me and my sister out for drinks but I realized right away that I didn't want to go out with him in a social setting like that although I enjoyed talking to him at work. over time he grew very fond of me and kept asking me out I agreed to go out on to dinner with him but after that I ended up blowing him off which caused a lot of resentment in the workplace. I even had to find a new job the treantment was too unfair but then i was promoted to manager and he is asking to hang out again. I only have one day off a week and I really don't want to spend it with him, so I don't know how to go about keeping the working friendship without having to make an excuse for why I can't hang out every weekend... is my job secure if I am honest and say no thank you I'm busy

Comment: That wall of text is a bit difficult to read. Some punctuation & formatting would go a long way.

Comment: You had to quit, but now you're manager at the same place? ... Other than that, we can't possibly know if your job is secure.

Comment: I think it's important that you make your point known. The owner may have kept you on purely in an attempt to go out with you. It's impossible to prove but overall what is clear is that it may worsen as the owner might feel that you are obligated to go out with him after several advancements. It's better to make it clear now that you're just not interested and hope that your position isn't compromised. Prepare yourself if such a thing happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I politely decline my boss's invitations to social events after-hours or on the weekend](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/55122/how-can-i-politely-decline-my-bosss-invitations-to-social-events-after-hours-or)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you were unhappy and found a new job but received an offer of a promotion and decided to stay.  The store owner is behaving unprofessionally and by leading you to believe that dating him is in any way related to how you are treated as an employee is likely sexual harassment.  Unfortunately the consequences of sexual harassment vary a lot by country so without know where you are from it's difficult to go into any more depth regarding that.  Stick to your guns and be honest "I'm not really interested in hanging outside of work."

Comment: I don't think what the OP said qualifies as sexual harassment. Just a persisting advancement that hasn't yet been fully answered with a firm yes or no. The OP needs to firmly say NO, I am NOT interested in going out with you now or ever. From there, the OP may lose her job as the owner may have kept her on just in the hopes of going out with her.

Comment: *which caused a lot of resentment in the workplace* I believe this statement strongly hints at  sexual harassment as her choosing not to accept his advances led to unfavorable treatment within the workplace.  Exact definition of sexual harassment will vary country to country but the Ontario human rights commission states "Section 7(3)(a) of the Code sets out a person's right to be free from unwelcome sexual advances or solicitation from a person who is in a position to grant or deny a benefit".